# Unity3d - 2d joint doesnt act as fixed joint

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a simple game object and attached the hinge joint 2d on it, but whenever the force is too great it causes a very weird effect that the sprites appear very far from each other, like a spring.

What I would like was the same effect as the fixed joint that works fine on 3d objects...

Anyone has suggestions ?

Comment: that sounds like an improper joint setup which cannot resolve its constraints (ie parts stuck within each other or in collisions)

Comment: They are not colliding with each other. One way to get around this is improving physics calculations per second, but, as everybody knows, it has an impact on performance. Im going to try this out to see how the performance goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Unity3D have a new type of joint called Fixed Joint and it does exactly what I was trying to achieve with simple 2d joint.